# startup script not being run on dl-platform

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-dl-platform

I am creating an instance like this:

```
gcloud compute instances create $(INSTANCE) \
    --machine-type a2-highgpu-1g \
    --provisioning-model=SPOT \
    --image-family $(IMAGE) \
    --image-project deeplearning-platform-release \
    --metadata install-nvidia-driver=True \
    --metadata-from-file startup-script=gce/bootstrap.sh,code=/tmp/code.tar
```

But it seems that the startup script never gets run because when I do:

```
gcloud compute ssh $(INSTANCE) \
    --zone $(ZONE) \
    --project $(COMPUTE_PROJECT) \
    --command "sudo journalctl -u google-startup-scripts.service"
```

the output is

```
-- Logs begin at Fri 2023-06-16 18:21:34 UTC, end at Mon 2023-07-24 18:28:29 UTC. --
-- No entries --
```

What am I doing wrong with the startup script?

Comment: I do not recognize `code=/tmp/code.tar` for `--metadata-from-file` in your create command. Have you looked at the entire log entries to see if there is an issue before the startup scripts are run?

Comment: Thanks for the response. The `code=/tmp/code.tar` was my attempt to a set a metadata variable "code", which gets used later in the startup script. How might I check whether there is an issue before the startup scripts are run?

Comment: Review the VM OS logs.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to debug it by accessing the VM instance then manually run the script. Normally the script is located in this directory /var/lib/google. Here is a documentation regarding start-up scripts that can be helpful for your case.[1]

[1] https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/startup-scripts